# Unable to recognize the audio in python while using SpeechRecognition

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

```
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("speak up:")
    a = r.listen(source)

    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print(text)
    except:
        print("sorry didn't get you")
```

even after talking the output is still

***sorry didn't get you***

Answer (score 0):

I am experienced with this package. Tell me if this works for you...

```
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:

        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print("User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Google was unable to hear")
        return "None"

    return query
```